# TweetSharp how to know that user has change/update his password

Tags: c#-4.0, tweetsharp

I have OauthToken and OauthSecretToken token use is as

```
 var service = new TwitterService(ClientInfo.ConsumerKey, ClientInfo.ConsumerSecret);
            service.AuthenticateWith(OauthToken , OauthSecretToken);
```

Is there any way to check that this user has changed his/her password.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Half the point of Oauth is that you never know anything about the users password.

Comment: I agree with you point , but can i know if is there any kind of update occurs on user profile.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know this. One of the purposes of OAuth is that applications have no way of knowing anything about the users password, so there's no way of knowing if the user has changed their password.